# automatic conversion from boost::bind_t to boost::function

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, c++03, boost-bind, boost-function

I have a method of the following signature:

```
template<typename T>
void
register_msg_action(const pmt::pmt_t& name,
      boost::function<T(pmt::pmt_t)> converter,
      boost::function<void(T)> action)
```

(`pmt_t` is a complete type, before you ask)

as well as overloads that take `T converter(pmt::pmt_t)` and `void converter(T)` (i.e. raw C/C++ functions), as well as all permutations of the above `boost::function<>` and the C-style function arguments. That leaves me with 4 different methods already.

I'd like to avoid increasing the number of methods further. However, the most common thing I'll do is call something like

```
register_msg_action(pmt::mp("key"),
    pmt::to_long, /* "raw" function long(pmt_t) */
    boost::bind(&my_class::void_method_of_long, this, _1) /* CAVEAT */
);
```

My approach was that the `/* CAVEAT */` argument is implicitly convertible to `boost::function<void(T)>`, but however, this doesn't seem to be the case (g++ 5.1.1):

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘register_msg_action(pmt::pmt_t, boost::function<long int(boost::intrusive_ptr<pmt::pmt_base>)>&, boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(long int), boost::_bi::list1<boost::arg<1> > >)’
     register_msg_action(pmt::mp("hi"), long_function, boost::bind(&my_class::void_method_of_long, this ,_1));
```

... all the other candidates (boost::function,boost::function); (T(pmt_t),boost::function); (T(pmt_t), void(T)) ...

```
test.cc:56:1: note: candidate: template<class T> void register_msg_action(const pmt_t&, T (*)(pmt::pmt_t), boost::function<void(T)>)
 register_msg_action(const pmt::pmt_t& name,
 ^
test.cc:56:1: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cc:80:76: note:   ‘boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(long int), boost::_bi::list1<boost::arg<1> > >’ is not derived from ‘boost::function<void(T)>’
     register_msg_action(pmt::mp("key"), pmt::to_long, boost::bind(&my_class::void_method_of_long, this, _1));
```

Now, doing

```
boost::function<void(long)> action (boost::bind(&my_class::void_method_of_long, this, _1));
register_msg_action(pmt::mp("key"), pmt::to_long, action);
```

works beautifully. Since there is even a constructor that takes `boost::_bi::bind_t` in `boost::function`, I wonder what I must do to make this work, *without*

- reimplementing `boost::function`
- relying on C++11 or later (can't do, legacy compiler support)
- using `boost:phoenix` for functional programming (would have tried this, but the boost versions we must support don't all have `phoenix` yet.

I'm afraid of adding the type of the third argument as additional template typename, because that would break the parameter list type safety that is necessary to guarantee `action(converter(pmt::pmt_t))` works, and honestly, I'd rather deal with more code now than examine user's templated g++ errors later on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is when `T` appears in the signature of `register_msg_action` within template arguments of `boost::function`. Then, if you're not calling it with an actual `boost::function` object, it cannot be deduced. It should work if you specify the template argument explicitly:

```
register_msg_action<long>(pmt::mp("key"),
    pmt::to_long, /* "raw" function long(pmt_t) */
    boost::bind(&my_class::void_method_of_long, this, _1)
);
```

If you want to keep the option of deducing `T` when using at least one plain-function argument, you have the option to explicitly make the `T` non-deducible in its `boost::function` use:

```
template <class T>
struct NonDeduced
{
  typedef T type;
};

// T has to be specified explicitly at call site
template<typename T>
void
register_msg_action(const pmt::pmt_t& name,
      boost::function<typename NonDeduced<T>::type (pmt::pmt_t)> converter,
      boost::function<void(typename NonDeduced<T>::type)> action)

// T deducible from converter
template<typename T>
void
register_msg_action(const pmt::pmt_t& name,
      T converter(pmt::pmt_t),
      boost::function<void(typename NonDeduced<T>::type)> action)

// T deducible from action
template<typename T>
void
register_msg_action(const pmt::pmt_t& name,
      boost::function<typename NonDeduced<T>::type (pmt::pmt_t)> converter,
      void action(T))

// T deducible from both, must match
template<typename T>
void
register_msg_action(const pmt::pmt_t& name,
      T converter(pmt::pmt_t),
      void action(T))
```

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e1dcc19efde86d81)

Comment: It does, indeed! I'll rework my syntax to make that a feature rather than an additional burden on the user.

Comment: By the way, forcing my user to specify the template argument would reduce my method number to 1, which is an improvement, I guess. I think it's better to force a user to do something explicitly than to offer him the chance to do something that would cause even someone with boost experience to take minutes to figure out what the compiler is complaining about.